# How do I use grid system on entry widget affected by .get()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
truth = ""
us = ""
uss = ""
     
root = Tk()
s = Label(root, text = ".")
s.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
wel = Label(root, text = "whats your email")
wel.grid(row = 1, column = 5)
inp = Entry(root).get()
inp.grid(row = 3, column = 5)
def callback():

   us = inp[:inp.index("@")]
   uss = inp[inp.index("@")+1:]
   truth =us, " is username, and ", uss,"is domain"
   print(truth)
sub = Button(root, text = "submit", command = callback)
sub.grid(row = 5, column = 5)
final = Label(root, textvariable = truth)
final.grid(row = 5, column = 6)

root.mainloop()
```

Then I get an error message:
'str' object has no attribute 'grid'

How do I use grid system on entry widget affected by .get()?

Comment: `inp = Entry(root).get()` is nonsensical.  Calling `.get()` on the Entry immediately after creating it can only return an empty string; when has the user had any chance to actually enter anything?  You need to do the `.get()` later, after the user has indicated that they're done typing.  Inside `callback()` would be the appropriate place in your case.